# Switch CloudKit from development to production via entitlements file

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I have an app with CloudKit with function to share some data with it.
In simulator and my device everything works almost perfectly.
But after installing the app through the TestFlight sharing does not work.

I deployed to Production my container in CloudKit site but it does not work.
I started googling about this problem and found out that i need to add in the entitlements file the row of com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment and set Production value.
But I can't figure out where to edit Entitlements file if I did all the necessary settings in Signing and Capabilities, push notification etc. Do I need to create this file myself? And if yes so where it should be located and do I need make something additional with it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI CloudKit syncing issue in TestFlight Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941924/swiftui-cloudkit-syncing-issue-in-testflight-only)

Answer (score 0):

As a novice developer I was having same problem and struggling for one week. It seems entitlements file is playing critical role to define "iCloud Container Identifiers" and "iCloud Services" keys in prod. They were under debug entitlements not in production. You may experience the same problem. It did not work when I added the row you mentioned but it worked when I added iCloud keys.
I think it is created automatically. You can see in your project folder with a gold seal mark icon similar to plist. You can edit same as you update info.plist. I found the clue here: [SwiftUI CloudKit syncing issue in TestFlight Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941924/swiftui-cloudkit-syncing-issue-in-testflight-only)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer that is basically a link to another answer, you should vote to close the question as a duplicate of the other question.